# Progressbar changing with int value

Tags: android, android-studio, int, progress-bar

Thank you for checking out this post, I am currently working on a school project and i'm making an calorie counter app. I'm almost finished and it's working perfect I have one problem however that I can't find a solution for anywhere.
I've got an int value that gives me the total number of calories, I would like this to be displayed in a horizontal progress bar so you can see how many calories you can still eat. Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Progress Bar Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html):

> setProgress(int progress)
>
> Set the current progress to the specified value.

So you can fix value to a progress bar with this method.

Comment: Thanks for this, I feel stupid now though :( but got it working!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a progress bar into your page and then assign a value like this :

```
 YourProgressBar.setProgress(Value);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I feel stupid now though :( but got it working!